# how to get different sequence id for each group when selecting -- in sql server 2000?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table like id,categoryId and sample data like

```
       id   categoryid
        1      74
        2      74
        3      75
        4      75
        5      76
        6      76
```

this.

I want my resulting data set like below.

```
        id   categoryid  row
         1      74        1
         2      74        1
         3      75        2
         4      75        2
         5      76        3
         6      77        4
```

can any one help me on this.
any reply will be thankful.

Comment: Where has categoryid 77 come from? Did you mean to put 77 in the sample data as well?

Comment: What have you yet tried? What tutorial or documentation could you not understand, that we could help you to understand?

Comment: sorry for mistakes, 77 is another category that i should have to mentioned on sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #tmp (id int, categoryid int)
create table #categoryid (categoryid int, sequencenumber int identity(1,1))

insert into #tmp values (1,74)
insert into #tmp values (2,74)
insert into #tmp values (3,75)
insert into #tmp values (4,75)
insert into #tmp values (5,76)
insert into #tmp values (6,77)

insert into #categoryid (categoryid)
select distinct categoryid
from #tmp
order by categoryid

select t.id, t.categoryid, c.sequencenumber
from #tmp t
join #categoryid c
    on t.categoryid = c.categoryid
```

It's amazing how quickly we forget how life used to be before ROW_NUMBER()... this may not be the best answer but it's the first one to pop into my head. Have fun!

Comment: I don't think `INSERT INTO`...`SELECT`...`ORDER BY` guarantees that you'll get the identity values in the specified order. Given that the question specifically asks about SQL Server 2000, where it'll work, that may be okay, but it's worth pointing out since it may prevent upgrading at a later stage to a more recent version of SQL Server.

Comment: @hvd, I apologize for my ignorance... I've never actually seen it not work and naturally assumed when something is ordered .. then inserted... it would work. Are you telling me this won't always work in SQL 2008/2012. For my education.. do you know of any documentation/blog that reveals this? Thanks.

Comment: In general, it's the lack of an explicit promise in the documentation that means you can't rely on it. However, it seems that in this case, I may have spoken too soon, as [Microsoft have specifically documented this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273586) (insofar as a KB article counts as documentation). So, +1 for you.

Comment: In summary... Identity functions are not reliable but identity columns are. Thanks for info, hvd!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2000, there is no built-in support for this. Newer versions of SQL Server support this with the `DENSE_RANK()` function:

```
select id, categoryid, dense_rank() over (order by categoryid) from sample;
```

but this has to be emulated to get something that works for 2000 too. Essentially, what the row number is, is the number of distinct categories (including the current one) seen so far, and that is easily expressed:

```
select id, categoryid, (
    select count(distinct categoryid) 
    from sample as sub 
    where categoryid <= sample.categoryid) 
from sample;
```